# Unable to query AS400 over ODBC with PolyBase on SQL 2019 Linux

Tags: sql-server, docker, odbc, db2-400, polybase

I would like to create external tables on a SQL Server 2019 instance running in an Ubuntu container querying an DB2 database on an AS400. I'm using the ibm iaccess 1.1.0.15 amd64 ODBC driver. When I try to create the external table, I get back the following error:

> Msg 105082, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
> 105082;Generic ODBC error: NativeOdbcConnection.Open, error in OdbcConnectionCreate: SqlState: , NativeError: 111234, 'Error calling: SQLDriverConnect(this->_hdbc, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)connectionString, SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, &cbConnStrOut, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT), SQL return code: -1 | SQL Error Info: **Internal DmsNative error: SQLGetDiagRec returned: -1 | ConnectionPooling: 1 | Error calling: pConn->Create(connectionString, databaseName, useConnectionPooling, packetSize, connectionLoginTimeout, environmentSettings, transactionToken, transactionTokenSize, resourceGroupName, driverCapabilities, spid) | state: FFFF, number: 1, active connections: 1', Connection String: Driver={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};system=MYAS400SYSTEM;uid=MYAS400UID;server=MYAS400.MYDOMAIN.com.

Here is the Dockerfile I am using

```
# SQL Server Command Line Tools - custom image
# From Ubuntu 20.04 as base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as base

# Installing system utilities
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl gnupg && \
    # Adding custom MS repository
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server-2019.list && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
# From base image
FROM base as release

# Add the SQL startup scripts
COPY . /usr/src/app

COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

# Grant permissions for the setupsql script to be executable
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/setupsql.sh

# Installing SQL Server drivers and tools
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y mssql-server-polybase
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools 
# Install the IBM iAccess ODBC Driver
RUN dpkg -i /usr/src/app/ibm-iaccess-1.1.0.15-1.0.amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -f
# Cleanup the Dockerfile
RUN apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists

CMD exec /bin/bash entrypoint.sh
```

I can connect to the SQL server instance in the container over localhost using SSMS. Creating the credential and the datasource are both successful. Creating the external table is where I get the error.

Here is the SQL script to create the external data source and external table:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AS400Credential
WITH IDENTITY = 'AS400UID',
SECRET = 'AS400PWD';  
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MYAS400 WITH (LOCATION = 'odbc://MYAS400.MYDOMAIN.com', 
   CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'DRIVER={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=MYAS400;', 
   PUSHDOWN = OFF,
   CREDENTIAL = AS400CREDENTIAL);
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EXT.Test 
(
    hstr NCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    hreg NCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    htr# NCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    httm NCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
WITH ( LOCATION='MYAS400DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE', DATA_SOURCE= MYAS400)
```

Any ideas on how to successfully connect to the AS400 using PolyBase?

Comment: Does this ODBC connection work _outside_ of Polybase?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the AS400 using the IBM i Access ODBC Driver with isql at the command line from inside the container. This command connects without issue:
```
isql -v -k "DRIVER={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};System=MYAS400;UID=MYUID;PWD=MIPWD;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PolyBase Generic ODBC connectivity is currently only available on Windows.

> This feature requires SQL Server on Windows.

[Configure PolyBase to access external data with ODBC generic types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-odbc-generic?view=sql-server-ver15)

Also currently [Linked Server to non-SQL Server targets, and External Access and Unsafe CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2019?view=sql-server-ver15#Unsupported) are Windows Only.

You may be able to use the [Python extensibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-machine-learning-docker?toc=%2Fsql%2Fmachine-learning%2Ftoc.json&view=sql-server-ver15) and [pyodbc](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/) to query your iSeries.

Comment: My ultimate goal was to run this as an Azure container instance. However, Windows containers can't join virtual networks from Azure container instance, only linux based containers.

Comment: SQL Server on Windows Containers is not officially supported in any case.